# Hola, debo hacer una lista de conteos de paquetes de un string en python

Tags: python

Tengo que desarrollar un programa que permita contar el numero de occurencias de un string sumarlo y mostrarlo acumulado en caso de que la letra sea repetida 3 veces "c" "c" "c" debe mostrar un 3 y si aparece una "b" debe empezar a sumar ese valor de modo que la impresion se deberia ver 3 1 y si vuelve a aparecer una "c" debe contarlo por aparte es decir imprimir 3 1 1 y no acumularla con el acumulador que inicialmente contaba c, y asi progresivamente.

tengo esto pero no me funciona y se que tengo fallas en mi logica, por eso pido ayuda.

def contar_elementos(elemento):
conteo=[0]
for caracter in elemento:
if caracter != elemento:
conteo.append(1)
else:
conteo[-1] += 1
return conteo

Comment: `if caracter != elemento:` Comparas una letra contra todo el texto. La condición siempre se cumplirá.

Comment: Ya lo he intentado de otra manera: `def contar_elementos(elemento):  
      contador = 0
      acumulador = 0
      for caracter in elemento:
        if caracter == 0:
          contador += 1
        if caracter == contador:
          continue
        else:
          contador + 0
      
      for caracter in elemento:
        if caracter == contador:
          acumulador += 1
        else:
          acumulador + 0 
` pero sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución simple:

```
def contar(texto):
    salida = []
    prev = None
    for letra in texto:
        if letra == prev:
            salida[-1] += 1
        else:
            salida.append(1)
            prev = letra
    return salida
```

La lista `salida` contiene la cuenta de las repeticiones de cada letra.

Se recorre el texto con un `for` extrayendo cada letra y comparándola con la anterior. Mientras sean iguales, se actualiza el contador a la cola de `salida`.

Cuando la letra cambia, se agrega una nueva cuenta en `1` y la letra recién leída pasa a ser la letra previa.

#### Demo

```
tests = [
    "",
    "a",
    "abc",
    "aaabbc",
    "aaaabbccaaabbbbcc"
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, contar(test))
```

produce:

```
 []
a [1]
abc [1, 1, 1]
aaabbc [3, 2, 1]
aaaabbccaaabbbbcc [4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Tu solucion fue de gran ayuda para mi, finalmente pude resolverlo de esta manera: {tupla = input()
tupla=tupla.upper()
tupla=tupla.replace(",","")

paquetes=[]
contador=[0]
paquetes.append(tupla[0])#creamos una lista que recorra la tupla inicial previamente convertida en lista para adicionarle esta tupla con .append y asi pueda recorrer cada uno de los elementos

for caracter in tupla:
        if caracter != paquetes[-1]:
          paquetes.append(caracter)
          contador.append(1)
        else:
          contador[-1]+=1}